How to not hate people?
I've been practising meditation for many years now but I feel like instead of becoming more compassionate and understanding I hate people more than ever. I notice so much their selfishness and lack of awareness of those around them etc. In particular I cannot tolerate loud people who don't seem to care about the noise pollution they subject others to. Social media has made everything worse. Seeing people constantly staring at their phones and taking selfies for their instagram etc makes me cringe. Narcissism seems to have become normal behaviour. Much of the time when I'm at home I wear ear plugs so I cannot hear the children screaming their heads off, dogs barking, people laughing and shouting, cars with unnecessarily loud mufflers, doors banging etc etc. Nature sounds I find soothing but people sounds I absolutely hate and feel very triggered. Instead of practising metta I find myself wishing people would drop dead.
So I know this is all not what Buddhism is about but it's how I feel and I feel conflicted about it.  Is this common? Is there something I should do to try and change it.  Metta practice feels useless to me. Its like pretending to feel kindness but underneath I feel nothing but hatred. Its just a glossing over.

"a healthy sense of the tragic"...idk

It's worth reflecting that we typically don't hate children, despite the fact that children are often noisy, rude, temperamental, self-centered, messy, and generally annoying. We don't hate children because we don't expect children to know better, or to have better self-control. We expect that of adults, so we get disappointed, so we get angry, and that anger solidifies into dislike. I'm thinking about this because I remember once I led an impromptu meditation group in a dorm common area, and a family with young kids walked through. The kids were running and laughing; the parents seemed embarrassed when they saw us; later one of the meditators complained about it at length… But it didn't have an impact on me. It was just a thing that happened, that came and went.
People's behavior isn't what gets to us. We expect them to behave differently (more 'maturely', or 'better'), and they don't; that's what gets to us.
It's the nature of human ego try and abolish space. Openness reminds the ego that its existence is small and limited, so it tries to fill up space with noise, movement, activity, etc, or to box some small space off that it can fill so it can ignore the rest. One of the traps of meditation, in fact, is to collapse your space down so that you are incognizant anything outside your own bubble. It's a trap because anything that penetrates that space (car alarms are a typical example) pops your meditation bubble and leaves you fuming.
The way out of this is to remind yourself that no amount of human activity can come close to filling open space. Open space is immense, quiet, and imperturbable. Every noise and action rises out of open space, is couched and enfolded within it, and disappears back to it. When you can touch that, then you see that all of the ridiculous, spastic, self-involved nonsense isn't something to hate. It's just the neurotic activity of egos trying to blind themselves from what they should accept as given. It doesn't dominate openness; it fears openness. You can accept these poor egos as they are or help them grow, as you choose. Otherwise it's no different from nature sounds, because you'll have no expectations that it should be different. Bird songs and car alarms both become mere sounds, rising and falling, appearing and disappearing, leaving openness untouched.

related: https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an10/an10.080.than.html

Hating people because they do not behave as we want does not solve any problem. It only gives us bad karma. Instead of hating, if you can teach others about Buddhism, it is the best way for you and society.
We can’t change everything around us, but we can change ourselves and teach others as we can. Even Buddha can not change everyone’s mind to follow the path to Nirvana.
So, practice metta and change your life according to pure Buddhist teachings, and teach them to others if you can. Don’t hate or wish bad things for others because it doesn’t make any change but collects bad karma for you.

Seon teacher Seung Sahn, talked about how going to be a hermit in an ice-cave in Tibet, is like meditating with training wheels. In the same teaching letter he says the best place to meditate would be somewhere like Main Street in New York, that if you can cultivate a meditative mind there, you can best bring the benefits to anyone in whatever circumstances. Meditating in perfect conditions is good to get started, to understand what a quiet mind is like, but our job as Buddhists is to carry that mind away from the mat too, noticing that just as in meditation we can choose which arising thoughts to cling to, or not.

"He abused me, he struck me, he overpowered me, he robbed me." Those
who do not harbor such thoughts still their hatred.
Hatred is never appeased by hatred in this world. By non-hatred alone
is hatred appeased. This is a law eternal.
There are those who do not realize that one day we all must die. But
those who do realize this settle their quarrels."
-from Ch1 of the Dhammapada

In the bigger picture, we all die,  approaching that how will you think about how you used your time, how you used your mind?
So, making a bridge to the traditional Buddhist views, from a modern mindset. Robert Sapolsky is an eminent biologist, and a leading sceptic of free will. He talks about how our wish to punish is often similar to how witch trials of the past blamed people for things they had no power over. A large majority of people in prison are functionally illiterate, and grew up in care, and a majority of people arrested for violent crimes have at some point recieved a traumatic head injury which we know damages impulse control. The death penalty almost never worked as a deterrent, because we know most murders are impulsive, and are generally over trivial things seen as about sicial status ('respect'), with rates very directly related to social inequality. We often feel like we alone are a rational disembodied mind, but we aren't. We need rules, and consequences acts so as to reduce harms, but we can recognise that when people have ill-will it doesn't just harm others, it harms themselves.
So, remember that we are animals, that we are all victims of our karma - the causes and conditions under which we came to be. For instance, the book 'Stolen Focus: How you are losing attention' by Johann Hari is great on unpicking the attention-economy, and how social media and it's impacts aren't something we chose, but actively exploit us and damage our mental health for profit. As Buddhists even with Awakening we cannot escape karma, we can only cease making it, allowing it eventually to extinguish. You are nursing or clinging to your negative feelings, which is what makes them triggers, creating karma, conditioning your mind to react.
Try to recognise positive moments, like make a practice of noticing and remembering each day, a moment when someone was considerate or kind. If you turn your attention to that, likely you will notice it happens more than you realised. Maybe that can be a first step, in shifting your attention.
Cultivating Bodhicitta is a primary practice for this Buddhist path. It means not just seeing the good in people, feeling compassion, but also recognising their suffering, need and capacity to awaken. They say all beings have been your father and mother, in a past life. Even more, all beings have the potential to be Buddhas - how precious! Honour that about them.
You too are suffering, so have compassion for yourself, for how you are putting this roadblock on your path. You can't stop what arises in your mind, but you can affect what you cling to and embellish - that is above all what meditation is, not the sitting, or any other external sign. We are not disembodied minds, so think about the circumstances of yourself and others, we all have our karma to face. But in every moment we have the opportunity to 'turn our wagon', away from suffering and the causes of suffering, away from locking our attention on to things that will coerce the behaviour of our mind, towards Unshakeable Liberation from the causes of suffering.
If your mind is struggling to quiten on the mat eg in response to noise, or as your meditation begins, use your attention to think of the challenges people face, of the problems and obstacles others have that you do not, notice the blessings you have had, and cultivate the wish that others have the opportunity you do, to open your heart and root yourself in this path by which hatreds can cease. But you can't simply mime the steps, you have to actually walk them, watching your mind and cultivating what will become wholesome 'triggers', and quieting the response to negative things by nit reacting, clinging to, or embellishing on your attebtion to them.
You might like this related answer, on how we should face evil: How should a bodhisattva respond to evil?

@blue_ego: .. hating people is pretty 'Pick a side of the fence!' ...

some animals like gazelle they flee. will they experience anxiety as a result? the gazelle doesn't have an ego to protect..idk

@blue_ego: Robert Sapolsky literally wrote a book on that, called 'Why Zebras Don't Get Ulcers' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_Zebras_Don%27t_Get_Ulcers We have hijacked a perfectly good system for short attention spans, & made the impacts on our mental & physical health, chronic. 'Ego' gets used to mean many things. Animals certainly have self awareness, evidenced by Mirror Tests, & sheep have been found able to distinguish at least 50 other sheep individuals (for humans we can put names to about 200 faces on average). Animals can certainly act on pride or hubris, to their detriment.

If the mind has a mental disposition towards discerning the myriad negative qualities of the world, we can try to use & transform this negativity into disenchantment (nibbindati) & dispassion (viraga). The Suttas say disenchantment & dispassion are the highest Dhamma qualities:

Of all the paths the Eightfold Path is the best; of all the truths the Four Noble Truths are the best; of all things dispassion (viraga) is the best: of men the Seeing One (the Buddha) is the best.
Dhammapada 273


To whatever extent there are phenomena conditioned or unconditioned, dispassion (viraga) is declared the foremost.
AN 4.34

The Suttas do not speak favourably towards the world, such as:

Blind is the world; here only a few possess insight. Dhammapada 174
This is called the perception of dissatisfaction with the whole world. AN 10.60

'Metta' itself is not mentioned in the Noble Eightfold Path. 'Metta' was/is an important teaching for those, such as monks, seeking to establish the Buddhist teaching in the world. However, today, much of the world is beyond the help of Dhamma & religion. We are at a time in history where is may be best for us to develop disenchantment & dispassion.
If our mind developments disenchantment & dispassion, our mind will reduce or even eliminate its expectations towards the world. When the mind is free from unrealistic expectations, hatred will cease & the mind will see the world as it truly is, which is the enlightened Buddha state of mind called 'suchness'.

I'm not really sure how to become disenchanted or dispassionate. I mean I am about some things. Is there a technique?

Thank you Sati. I suppose what i posted may not be easily but it is seeing the short-comings of the things you are already seeing until you, without resistance, acknowledge them for what they are. In other words, the mind realises these negative things of the world is simply the way the world must inevitably be. For example, for the most part, people are selfish. This is the truth. We cannot escape the truth/reality that people are selfish. Therefore, we must sadly accept this truth. I myself must always practice like this.

So if I am having a reaction or resistance to it do you think it means I have not accepted it?  What about war and poverty etc?

Yes. Buddhism explains the world arises from ignorance. Most people in the world have minds controlled by ignorance. Our goal as Buddhists is to try to end the ignorance in our mind. Part of this ignorance is not understanding ignorance.

I know, it is difficult at times to deal with other people‘s anger and behaviour, which seem to invade one‘s own let‘s call it „privacy“.
However, realizing that ever single individual out there that you mention, is an individual who is hurting in their own way, dealing with issues - maybe like you -, who tries to be happy, tries to succeed, tries and tries - and who might just as well fail time and time again, creates a feeling of compassion.
Hate does not exist when we love. You don‘t need to love them, but seeing in these people the suffering, may make you more empathic towards them and alleviate you from your own suffering through their behaviour that seems to hurt you.
Empathy, compassion and love help us leave our own ego-states behind and open us up. And by doing so, you‘re not only engaging more positively with the world around you - but you are also healing when coming in contact with it.
This man / woman was once a child, with dreams, hope and ambitions. Some of them were fulfilled, many others were crushed. The expression that this person is showing right now, is an expression of pain and suffering. At their core they still want to be happy and they do - as they do - because they believe that this will be the path to their happiness, even though I might not agree with that path that they have chosen for their lives.

Is that quote from somewhere else? Could you cite the source?

I truly believe that I wrote this, I am sorry, I cannot quote a source.

Perhaps you are missing the cues in the practice. When you notice selfish and inconsiderate behaviour, do you also notice the desire within the mind that demands these people cease behaving in those manners? More importantly, do you see the pain and suffering that the desire is inflicting?
Ajahn Chah once said craving is like a red-hot iron, once we are aware of its burning nature i.e. the resulting suffering it causes, we will let go of it in an instance.

Craving not to experience something, craving to be at peace, craving not to be distracted and agitated - it's all craving. It's all a red-hot chunk of iron.

So why don’t we drop our desires in an instance? We had a choice but instead we chose to just ignored them and let them stay as guests in our mind. We treated them as normal and find excuses for their existence. Afterall, what is wrong with being offended by inconsiderate and selfish behaviour? People should not tolerate insufferable fools around them. But why stop here. We should ensure that the world become malleable to our will and reality, itself, conform to our desires, right? Hmmmm....
We can see how a certain line of reasoning leads to eventual problems and the avalanche of sufferings that unfold. By ignoring, justifying and excusing our desires instead of directly confronting and penetrating its nature, we brushed aside and ignored the stress they created. I am not saying we should put up with wrongful behaviour. But there is a more important aspect of the training than noticing wrongful behaviour. It is noticing the hot burning iron within us and why, strangely, we just won’t let it go. We may not be able to put an end to another’s wrongful behaviour or even those of our own. But we can put an end to the red-hot chunk of iron within our mind now and enjoy the moment of peace it brings until the next hot iron comes along. Then, we will drop that too and the next one after that and so on. Soon, we will become good at doing this. Who knows, maybe one day these moments of peace will eventually stretch out and connect into one continuous stream. Lastly, I think practising the Dharma isn’t all struggling and enduring, it can be fun, interesting, joyful and rewarding.

I understand this but for some reason I don't always live it. I still feel very triggered by things but don't always react anymore.  I now live almost as a recluse because I find it all very painful but I cannot stop the noise except with the help of earplugs.   I meditate a lot and I attend retreats and looking back I have changed quite significantly but still there is a sense of very deep disappointment with people and the world.  Death seems like something nice to look forward to tbh.

This deep disappointment is driven by an equally deep desire. I would suggest trying to reflect and identify this desire. It may be painful to dig up something buried deeply within. But it is necessary and in accordance with the process of the four noble truths. There is disappointment (dukkha), it is caused by desire but exactly what desire? There is a temptation to avoid identifying and let things remain hidden. But doing so would only means being stuck, unable to progress.

Talk to the inner self, try to understand its wants, whims and fancies. Discuss and try to reach an understanding i.e. an understanding w.r.t one’s abilities and limitations to fulfill them. Apologise to our inner self that although we really tried our best, but sometimes, the best just isn’t good enough. Then, forgive ourselves for our limitations, make peace. With it the realization while we will never have the world; we can always be at peace with ourselves. We all eventually dies but dying without peace just sucks.

I think I harbour a lot of anger. I feel wronged by people. This most likely stems from my childhood and teen years when I was bullied and ostracised by my peers and was at the receiving end of my parents anger. They lashed out at me very aggressively.  After that I went through a period of drug addiction. Now I just have this deep distrust and dislike of most people. I don't know how to change this. Meditation brings some peace but there's still this hurt little boy/self who just wants to protect himself by hiding/isolating.

Then I go online and read things/see things that seem to validate my perception that people are just nasty and the world is horrible place. Of course I know this must be a distortion but I cannot seem to change it. I feel safe just being alone. Hating people and seeing myself as not like them must be a self protection mechanism.

If you look really deep within, is there a sense of disappointment, resentment and bitterness towards yourself and your life?

SN 1.71

Having killed anger
you sleep in ease.
Having killed anger
you do not grieve.
The noble ones praise
the slaying of anger
—with its honeyed crest
& poison root—
for having killed it
you do not grieve.


"desire breeds anger" :(
